# Como filtrar uma tabela com o valor de uma célula em outra sheet?

Tags: excel-vba

uma sheet(1) contém a base de dados com seu cabeçalho, na sheet(2) quero acrescentar um valor a uma célula e rodar o código, onde posso alterar o valor da célula e mudar o filtro na outra sheet sem usar formulário. o meu da erro não traz informação só filtra:

cod: sheet(1).range("A1").autofilter  field:=1, criteria1:= sheet(2).range("B2").value
o codigo não vai, tentei q=criando uma variável e guardando o valor da célula da sheet(2), depois chamar ela no criteria e não foi. como posso resolver isso? tem como?

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Não vou votar negativo (como alguém fez), mas vou dar um feedback, o que é mais construtivo: está um pouco difícil entender sua pergunta. Algumas dicas:

Comment: Tente usar a formatação adequada, como as backticks triplas para demarcar o que é código do que é sua fala. Tente usar maiúsculas e minúsculas e, em geral, a gramática, que está sendo uma certa dificuldade ao interpretar sua pergunta (essa dica é para a vida).

Comment: Na linha ```cod: sheet(1).range("A1").autofilter field:=1, criteria1:= sheet(2).range("B2").value```, eu acho que o ```cod: ``` no começo é um erro do seu código, não? Creio que o VBA não conhece essa instrução (a não ser que seja uma label e você esqueceu de quebrar a linha).

Comment: Por fim, o que é "tentei q=criando uma variável"? Não consegui entender essa frase.

Comment: obg pela sugestão, sou novo na plataforma estou me habituando. O que quero perguntar é simples, se tem alguma maneira de filtrar uma tabela com informação de um célula.  coloquei o código que usei para fazer isso, onde não deu certo. tentei guardar o valor em uma variável e também não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

achei uma solução para o problema, na verdade acho que sei onde estava o erro.
como meu valor que queria filtrar era data, estava guardando a variável como Date e quando chamava a variável no critério de filtro não trazia nada. Então troquei o *tipo* para *String* e quando chamei a variável filtrou o valor da data que estava na célula que referenciei.

Dim Data As **String** -> (reservando o tipo da variável)
Data = **worksheets("2").Range("B2").Value**

**sheet(1).range("A1").autofilter field:=1, _
criteria1:=Data.value**